# Apache no suitable image found in httpd.conf when running apachectl configtest

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I had Apache 2.2 set up on my Windows machine without issue. I am moving to a Mac and 2.4 and am stuck.   So this question is for my Mac setup.

I am using Apache from Homebrew.  I am getting this error when I run apachectl configtest

```
apachectl configtest
httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so 
into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so, 10):
no suitable image found.  
Did find:
\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so: unknown file type, 
first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so: unknown file type, 
first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

Here is the line in my httpd.conf that is failing.

```
LoadModule weblogic_module /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so
```

---

Machine set up:

```
Java 8:
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_181, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

WebLogic Server:
12.2.1.3.0 Thu Aug 17 13:39:49 PDT 2017 1882952

---

```
apachectl -l
   Compiled in modules:
     core.c
     mod_so.c
     http_core.c
```

Comment: Looks like you have non-visible characters in your configuration file.  In your LoadModule line, make sure you have nothing else than a single space between "weblogic_module" and "/usr/...".

Comment: I have a single space between weblogic_module and /usr/local.....  I verified this by viewing all characters.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a ton of searches on Google, it was a Bing query that finally led me down the correct path.  A Bing query on 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00  told me my mod_wl_24.so was not going to work on my  Mac.  Then further searches seemed to confirm this.

So I am just using mod_proxy.so that came with Apache.  I then added these lines to prove it worked

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7001/
</VirtualHost>
```

I still have some work to do, but solved the initial issue.